Problem with `PolynomialSumOfSquaresList` documentation. I get difference output
In the newest documentation https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PolynomialSumOfSquaresList.html I read that

However, on Mathematica 14.1.0 I tested the same code and it didn't fail

Is the documentation wrong?

Clearly the documentation is wrong. Please report to WRI  support@wolfram.com


The point that the documentation is making is still valid, namely PolynomialSumOfSquaresList uses machine-precision numeric algorithms, so it may fail even if a sum of squares representation exists. Giving specific examples where this happens is a moving target. As the numeric algorithms get improved, examples that didn't work may start working. It looks like we need new documentation examples...
